# Error: La extension msqli esta desactualizada en php en mi panel?

Tags: php

Hola cuando intento loguearme a mi panel por medio de la siguiente linea de codigo:

```
mysql_connect($server, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db);
```

Me devuelve el error:

```
Msql esta desactualizado.
```

Entonces lo que hago es pasarlo a msqli:

```
mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass);
mysqli_select_db($db);
```

pero me devuelve:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Podria intentar rehacer la conexion en PDO pero a lo mejor usando msqli y los dos parametros que me pide seria suficiente? cual es el otro parametro que he de poner?

Comment: Lo que te dice Einer es lo correcto, pero modifica mysql por mysqli

Answer (score 1):

El primer parametro es la conexion al servidor de base de datos de la cual vas a utilizar y el segundo es el nombre de la base de datos a utilizar. Seria así:

```
$conexion= mysql_connect($server, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($conexion, $db);
```

Aunque deberias de utilizar [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) ya que esas funciones esta obsoletas